# pigeonhole principle proof for 10 kings in a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, chessboard

There are 10 kings in a chessboard. prove that there is one square in the board that creed with 2 kings.

Comment: @Crostul I know each king if go on the corner of the board, cover 4 squares, and if it go on the walls of the board it cover 6 squares , and if it go somewhere else it will cover 9 squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the board into 3x3 regions as much as possible, like this:

```
a a a b b b c c
a a a b b b c c
a a a b b b c c
d d d e e e f f
d d d e e e f f
d d d e e e f f
g g g h h h i i
g g g h h h i i
```

Each region obviously can contain at most one king (else they would be attacking each other, or both cover the central square of the region).
There are 9 regions, so at most 9 kings are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: When you "place a king" on the board, instead of tracking exactly where you put the king, trace how many squares that king touches. Might need to handle some special cases when the king is placed in a corner or on an edge, but I believe that this approach might give you a solution.

Comment: thank you for your hint, I know each king if go on the corner of the board, cover 4 squares, and if it go on the walls of the board it cover 6 squares , and if it go somewhere else it will cover 9 squares

Comment: Yes. Now try to minimize the total number of squares your 10 kings "occupy" also using the geometry of the chess board (how many corners are you allowed to use? How many edges?)

Comment: @WillCraig Maybe I miss something but let's say we put a king in each cormer which covers $16$ cells. Then you can put exactly $4$ kings on every edge, which covers $24$ cells. Then you cannot really conclude right ?

Comment: Let's rethink this - If you place a king in a corner, yes he occupies 4 slots, but is that really the number that other kings now can't take? I believe there are more.